# Too Many onEdit scripts running under 1 master onEdit ? GoogleSheets / Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just added the script Move(e) to my master onEdit running 4 other onEdit scripts. As soon as I did, Move(e) doesnt work ? Is there a limit to how many onEdits you can run - like what I have done here ?

```
function onEdit(e) {

AddPalletCount(e);
CapitaliseData(e),
MoveThenDelete(e),
Move(e),
AddTimeStamp(e)
}

function Move(e) {
var sh=e.range.getSheet();
if(sh.getName()!='HOLDING')return
if(e.range.columnStart==6 && e.value== "TRUE") {
var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('HOLDING To CDS');
var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,5).copyTo(trg);


}}
```

As always thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminate your lines with semicolons. `;` not commas

```
function onEdit(e) {
  AddPalletCount(e);
  CapitaliseData(e);
  MoveThenDelete(e);
  Move(e);
  AddTimeStamp(e);
}

function Move(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='HOLDING')return
  if(e.range.columnStart==6 && e.value== "TRUE") {
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('HOLDING To CDS');
    var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,5).copyTo(trg);
  }
}
```